# How to choose AEM component for dialog and component creation

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am new to AEM (6.5),

I found different components in different locations, each component is used in component creation and dialog creation. I am confused, which component is suitable for which purpose?
ie. for dialog creation and custom component creation and extending components.

Please tell me the bellow components purpose or differents or when to use it.

1 . /libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation
2. /libs/granite/ui/components/foundation
3. /libs/foundation/components
4. /libs/wcm/foundation/components
5. /libs/cq/gui/components/authoring
6. /apps/core/wcm/components

Comment: Adobe recommends the use of category one (and two). The others are legacy and provide compability for older code. Feel free to ask https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/ct-p/adobe-experience-manager-community for more details.

Answer (score 1):

[1] - Overlay Component: component by copying a foundation component to your project and extending based on requirement.

/libs/foundation/components --copy to--- > /apps//components

[2] - Override Component : creating component nodes and setting value of sling:resourceSuperType property as "/libs/foundation/components/"

[3] - Proxy pattern component from core component: Override component from /apps/core/wcm/components to your aem app /apps/your-app/components

in these all three [3] Proxy pattern one is better approach when you are planning to implementation with latest terminology and also [1] and [2] is not recommended since whenever planning of upgrade in AEM therefore best approach is [3]rd, since it will be helping to make project upgrade free and multiple version of core component also give you advantage over.